# template used in class involving a generic comparison function

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a Bheap in templates and the insert function involving a generic comparison function. What is the usual way to do this? I know how to use function pointer in C. But Is there any typical C++ way to do that?

Someone told the first one, which class F could represent anything any function. But I want this function to be a comparison function which like f(T,T). While the second guy say something about the functors

```
  template <class T, class F>class Bheap
{
public:
    Bheap<T>(int allocateSize);
    void insert(T value, F f);
    void getMax();
private:
    int sizeUsed;
    int allocateSize;
    vector<T> myBheap;
};
```

Comment: If the functor passed as `F` doesn't fit your requirements of having 2 arguments, then your compiler will let you know.  That is what you want to have, and that is the compiler stopping the user from giving you an improper function.

Comment: I did not define f there, how does the compiler know I need 2 arguments exactly.

Comment: Is it ok to use [C++11](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/)?

Comment: how please tell me thanks!

Comment: Implement your usage of `F`.  In the usage, you will write it expecting 2 arguments.  When the compiler sees that the (bad) functor is only suitable for one argument, you get the compiler error.  In other words, don't worry about it.  Let the compiler do the detection work for you.

Comment: The assumption is that the implementation of `insert` will involve calling the `f` parameter with two arguments, which won't compile unless `f` is a function of two arguments.

Comment: thanks, another question then the definition of the class involves two templates, is it usual way to do that? What will you do when realizing a similar question.

Comment: Please don't chain questions, ask new questions instead. But yes, it's perfectly reasonable for a class to have many template parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement your class and the `insert` function, assuming whatever is passed is correct in terms of the number of arguments.  If the number of arguments is not 2, the compiler will let you know.

This is the desired effect in these cases.  Let the compiler detect that the function is not valid, and thus the user has to change the function to the correct requirements.

A demonstration using your code would be this:

```
#include <vector>

template <class T, class F>
class Bheap
{
public:
    Bheap(int allocateSize) {}
    void insert(T value, F f)
    {
        f(value, value);
    }
    void getMax();
private:
    int sizeUsed;
    int allocateSize;
    std::vector<T> myBheap;
};

void SomeFunction(int, int)
{}

int main()
{
    typedef void (*fn)(int, int);
    Bheap<int, fn> b(10);
    b.insert(10, SomeFunction);
}
```

You will see that this compiles and links correctly (I used a function pointer, but a functor with an overloaded `operator()` would also suffice).

Now if the user's function is changed to one that takes 1 argument, we get a different scenario:

```
#include <vector>

template <class T, class F>
class Bheap
{
public:
    Bheap(int allocateSize) {}
    void insert(T value, F f)
    {
        f(value, value);
    }
    void getMax();
private:
    int sizeUsed;
    int allocateSize;
    std::vector<T> myBheap;
};

void SomeFunction(int)
{}

int main()
{
    typedef void (*fn)(int);
    Bheap<int, fn> b(10);
    b.insert(10, SomeFunction);
}
```

The invalid function will make your class fail to compile.  Since your template requires a 2 argument function, passing a 1 argument function via pointer causes the error (which you can see here: http://ideone.com/rT7RRa)

---

For function objects, here is an example of successful compilation:

http://ideone.com/yvWD5o

For unsuccessful compilation:

http://ideone.com/yjeAWB

Comment: could you also share some way to use functor rather than function pointer here? since I have finished a course in C which does function pointer a lot. thanks

Comment: @airbender Added links to show compilation results when using a function object.

Answer (score 0):

A functor is a struct providing one or more overloads of operator (), which makes it a choice if you have several comparisons:

```
// Having a struct X { K key, V value };
struct Less {
    template <typename K, typename V>
    operator bool () (const X<K, V>& a, const X<K, V>& b> const { 
        return a.key < b.key;
    }
    template <typename K, typename V>
    operator bool () (const X<K, V>& a, const K& b> const { 
        return a.key < b;
    }
    template <typename K, typename V>
    operator bool () (const K& a, const X<K, V>& b> const { 
        return a < b.key;
    }
};
```